# Flatten data using linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class A
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public List<B> Values { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }          
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string X { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public string ValueB1X { get; set; }
    public string ValueB2X { get; set; }
    ...
    public string ValueBnX { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }  
}
```

I need to convert List of A into List of Result. Any idea how can that be done with LINQ?
Basically what I need is this:

```
A[0] = |Value1|Value2|Value2|
        B[0]
        B[1]
        B[2]

A[1] = |Value1|Value2|Value2|
        B[0]
        B[1]
        B[2]
```

converted to

```
              +------------------------------------------------------+
     rowA[0]  | Value1 | Value2 |  B[0].X | B[1].X | B[1].X | Value3 |
     rowA[1]  | Value1 | Value2 |  B[0].X | B[1].X | B[1].X | Value3 |
```

Comment: Are there always going to be exactly three items in the list of `B`s?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know how many `B` you will have, because the `Result` class needs to be written to accomodate that number of items. So this is not a dynamic solution that would work any number of `B` like you seem to imply (1..n)

A better design would be

```
public class Result 
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }     
    public int Value2 { get; set; }     
    public List<B> BValues { get; set; }
}
```

or, assuming the `B` `Id`s are always unique,

```
public class Result 
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }     
    public int Value2 { get; set; }     
    public Dictionary<int, string> BValues { get; set; }
}
```

and then construct a dictionary -

```
List<A> list = GetList();
List<Result> result = list.Select(a =>
    new Result()
    {
        Value1 = a.Value1,
        Value2 = a.Value2,
        BValues = a.Values.ToDictionary(b => b.Id, b => b.X)
    });
```

Comment: Your Result class looks very similar to Class A that I started with. (except now its a Dictionary).
Also I don't need IDs from class B, just Xs. (I added IDs just to show that B is complex class)
What I really need is list of class B separated into variables and added to class A in the Result.
Result class can be anonymous.

Comment: You can't dynamically create concrete types in a strongly typed language. You can easily put all the Xs into a collection - list, dictionary, etc - but you can't dynamically create properties. A good question to you would be **why**? How are you going to use this `Result` object?